# Crystal report printing/ PDF file printing

Tags: asp.net, pdf, printing, crystal-reports

I am using crystal report 11, ASP .NET 3.5

I want any clue/suggestions for printing crystal report without viewing the data in crystalreportviewer.

One option i have is to export the crystal report to PDF and then print.
But how can i print PDF file without opening it.I do not want to specify the printer from code.

I want to select the printer from print dialogue box.The printer could be network printer.

I would also like to know whether there is any third party tool.

Please provide your suggestions.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

In my asp.net web app I use Crystal to generate a PDF that gets streamed to the client.
That requires that the users have to have a PDF viewer installed.

Some of my code:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string repName = Request.QueryString.Get("report");

    ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
    rpt.Load(Server.MapPath(repName));

    System.IO.Stream oStream;
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    oStream = rpt.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
    byteArray = new byte[oStream.Length];
    oStream.Read(byteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(oStream.Length - 1));
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, Your answer solved my problems. Thanks you very much. I found your answer in google.